# Can we conclude that the given stochastic process $X_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu t,\sigma^2 t)$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, moment-generating-functions

We know that for any $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, the following equality holds:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(\beta X_t)\right]=\exp\left(\mu \beta t+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \beta^2 t\right)
$$
Can we conclude that $X_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu t,\sigma^2 t)$?

---

I notice that the moment generating function uniquely determines the distribution. Hence, we can get the desired result directly.

Comment: Yes you can conclude that!